# ggplot graph with two groups, each displaying their separate error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add error bars to my graph using `ggplot()`. Is there a way to add error bars for two groups in a `ggplot()` graph?

I know that this code will give me error bars for one of my groups:

```
geom_linerange(aes(ymin=percentBias-normSEM, ymax=percentBias+normSEM),
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.05), col='red')
```

The dependent variable is percent bias (y-axis) and the x-axis displays the range of variability (1 to 8). I have two groups that I am graphing: Normal and Uniform. I would like to display both groups in the graph with their error bars, normSEM and uniSEM, respectively. Error bars are the standard error of the mean for each group. The code above applies the same error bars (normSEM) to everything.

Comment: Convert your data to long form and use your code by group.

Comment: Please post a small reproducible sample of data - `dput()` is the nicest way to do this because it is copy/pasteable. E.g., `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows.

Comment: Also, it seems you've asked several questions that have been answered, but only "accepted" an answer for one question - I'd suggest going back to your old questions and accepting answers if they helped you. It's a nice way to say thank you to the answerers, and to indicate that the issue is resolved.

Comment: I totally agree with Gregor. Although most of the people on this site are answering questions because they want to be helpful, providing some internet points to show your thanks for a helpful solution is appreciated.

Comment: I'm new to this platform and had no idea about these aspects. Thank you for informing me that I can do this as a thank you to other. @GregorThomas